# Названия населенных пунктов на карте Яндекс при наличии собственного оверлея

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Существует ли в Яндексе возможность при наложении на карту Яндекс своего Overlay сделать так, чтобы при этом названия городов и т.д. оказались сверху overlay? У меня сейчас эти названия остались снизу (под моим оверлеем) и поэтому часть названий просто не видна. Прозрачность оверлея меня не устраивает, так как все должно быть видно (http://innovation.org.ru/index.php изображение справа).

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: http://innovation.org.ru/index.php изображение справа - здесь хорошо видно, что оверлей закрыл часть названия города Севастополь. Как это избежать и увидеть название целиком?